# Xpath works in chrome dev tools but not in python

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I would like to extract comments from this webpage http://g1.globo.com/sao-paulo/noticia/camara-municipal-de-sp-aprova-concessao-do-pacaembu-a-iniciativa-privada.ghtml

I use this xpath:

```
.//div[contains(@itemprop, "creator")]/p[contains(@class, "glbComentarios-texto-comentario")]/text()
```

And works perfectly on chrome dev tools:

[result print of xpath on web page g1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzgde.png)

This is my code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html

page = requests.get('http://g1.globo.com/sao-paulo/noticia/camara-municipal-de-sp-aprova-concessao-do-pacaembu-a-iniciativa-privada.ghtml')

tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

comments = tree.xpath('.//div[contains(@itemprop, "creator")]/p[contains(@class, "glbComentarios-texto-comentario")]/text()')
```

But I only get an empty list. I've also tried scrapy and BeautifulSoup, but I was not successful either.

Comment: this is because of javascript rendering, the information you want isn't in the same original request. You'll have to check the requests that are being dynamically generated and in which one of those is the information you are looking for.

Comment: Because the source is HTML rather than XML, there's more than one way of creating an instance of the XPath data model representing the HTML, and the two tools may be doing it differently. Check (a) whether the names of the elements in the constructed tree are upper or lower case, and (b) whether the elements are in the XHTML namespace.

Comment: It is not work in firefox